# TeeChart for Xamarin.Forms with Windows 8 (WinRT) apps

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, xamarin.forms, teechart

We have a Xamarin.Forms app that also supports Windows 8/8.1 as a platform. Xamarin.Forms has support for WinRT and that's how it can be deployed to Windows 8/8.1.

We are using TeeCharts for Xamarin.Forms however, it doesn't seem to support WinRT as a platform. Is there a way to use TeeCharts for Xamarin.Forms with Windows 8/8.1?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid TeeChart for Xamarin.Forms doesn't support WinRT (Windows 8/8.1).
However, TeeChart.Store.dll should be able to target this environment without problems. Please, contact "info at steema dot com" - referencing this post - for further instructions about how to get it.